# Composition vs Product of Linear Functions

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to understand why the product of two matrices is the same as the composition of the linear maps that the matrices represent.  To do so, I consider some simply linear mappings:
$y_1(x) = 3x$ and $y_2(x)=4x$

The composition of these two mappings is $(y_1 \circ y_2)(x) = y_1(4x) = 12x$, but the product of these two mappings is $(y_1 y_2)(x) = (3x)(4x)=12x^2$.  These are clearly not the same.

It gets even worse if I move up in dimensions.  Consider the linear mappings given by $(x,y) \stackrel{f}{\mapsto} (2x,3y)$ and $(x,y) \stackrel{g}{\mapsto} (4x,-y)$.  The composition of these, $(f \circ g)(x,y)= (8x,-3y)$ is perfectly well defined, but what about the product?  I can't simply multiply them like $(fg)(x,y)$, because $f(x,y)g(x,y)$ is undefined (or maybe I should say, it's unclear which product we should use between these two vector-valued functions).

So what am I doing wrong here?  How can I reconcile the idea that the composition and product of linear mappings should be the same operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the product of matrices and the product of functions.  If $f(x) = Ax$ and $g(x) = Bx$ are linear mappings with matrices $A$ and $B$, then the composition is $f(g(x)) = A(Bx) = ABx = (AB)(x)$.

For your first example, $y_1(x) = 3x$ and $y_2(x) = 4x$, so here $A = [3]$ and $B=[4]$ are the matrices.  The product $AB = [12]$, which is exactly what you found for $f_1\circ f_2$.

For the second example, your matrix for $f$ is $A=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}$ and the matrix for $g$ is $B = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$.  Then the product is $AB = \begin{bmatrix} 8 & 0 \\ 0 & -3 \end{bmatrix}$ which is the matrix for $f\circ g$.

Answer (score 0):

The linear mappings you have take 
$$x\mapsto 3x$$
$$x\mapsto 4x$$

so actually the matrices you have are 1$\times$1 and they are $3$ and $4$ respectively.

In the multivariate case, the matrices you have are
\begin{pmatrix}
  2 & 0 \\
  0 & 3 
 \end{pmatrix} 
and

\begin{pmatrix}
  4 & 0 \\
  0 & -1 
 \end{pmatrix}

In fact, if you multiply the two, you get
\begin{pmatrix}
  8 & 0 \\
  0 & -3 
 \end{pmatrix}